# Nginx configuration for Laravel in subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-5

I have placed my Laravel 5 project in `/var/www/my_project/` and I would like to reach it at `http://my_domain.com/my_project/`. However, I can't figure out how to configure the nginx server block.

What I want is this:

- `http://my_domain.com/` should be empty at this point. Later, another project will be visible here.
- `http://my_domain.com/my_project/` should be the project I am trying to add now.

Please note that the Laravel public folder is located at `/var/www/my_project/public`.

This is my nginx configuration (at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/my_project/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name my_ip;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

What is the best way to achieve the desired configuration?

Comment: Very good question. It needs quite good work to make laravel app with another app work on same virtualhost

Comment: what you want is an alias, leave your root as `/var/www/` and add a location as `location /my_project {
    alias /var/www/my_project/public;
  }`

Comment: Fabio, that is one of the configurations I have tried, but it doesn't work. `http://my_domain.com/my_project/` returns the nginx/Ubuntu 404 page. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put your `laravel` project in a `subfolder` on a server with `ngnix-ubuntu 16-php.7.2`, so here is update ngnix config :

1) your nested(subfolder) isn't inside your main folder

```
/var/www/main:
/var/www/nested:
```

then your config :

```
location /nested {

        alias /var/www/nested/public;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

               location ~ \.php$ {
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

                                }
   }

location @nested {
        rewrite /nested/(.*)$ /nested/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

2) your laravel-test folder (subfolder) inside your main :

```
/var/www/main:
/var/www/main/nested:
```

then your config :

```
location /laravel-test {

    alias /var/www/main/laravel-test/public;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @laravelTest;

           location ~ \.php$ {
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

                            }


  }

location @laravelTest {
        rewrite /laravel-test/(.*)$ /laravel-test/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. And  other answers didn`t woked

```
location /rmbdatamis/ {
    root            /home/baiduwork/rmb-odp/webroot;
    index index.php;
    include     fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass $php_upstream;
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/rmbdatamis/(.*) /rmbdatamis/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
}
```